# replacing matching columns using sed/awk/

Tags: shell, sed, awk

How can I achieve this using awk/sed or any other scripting commands.

1) Read a file with many rows containing 26 digits in each line
2)Using shell scripting replace 07 with 08 only in 25th and 26th column of each row if 07 is found

Thankyou.

Comment: How are the columns separated in a given row, white space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk`

```
awk  'BEGIN{FS=""; OFS=""}{if ($25$26 == "07") {$25="0"; $26="8"}{print}}'
```

Comment: I didn't know I can specify FS="". Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if you are sure each row in your file has 26 digits. (length 26), you could:

```
sed 's/07$/08/' file
```

Comment: Thanks kent. Is there a generic way of doing it. Say I specify column and the digit to replace as parameters to the script.

Comment: @irappa yes you can try `sed -r 's/(.{24})07(.*)/\108\2/'` If the requirement is like that, I would do it with sed.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^(.{24})07/\108/' file
```